# Path assignment to setwd() is delayed in for/foreach loop

Tags: r, setwd

The objective is to change within a for loop the current working directory and do some other stuff in it,.e.g. searching for files. The paths are stored in generic variables.
The R code I am running for this is the following:

```
require("foreach")

# The following lines are generated by an external tool and stored in filePath.info 
# Loaded via source("filePaths.info")
result1 <- '/home/user/folder1' 
result2 <- '/home/user/folder2'
result3 <- '/home/user/folder3' 
number_results <- 3

# So I know that I have all in all 3 folders with results by number_results 
# and that the variable name that contains the path to the results is generic: 
# string "result" plus 1:number_results.

# Now I want to switch to each result path and do some computation within each folder
start_dir <- getwd()
print(paste0("start_dir: ",start_dir))

# For every result folder switch into the directory of the folder
foreach(i=1:number_results) %do% { 
# for (i in 1:number_results){ leads to the same output

    # Assign path in variable, not the variable name as string: current_variable <- result1 (not string "result1")
    current_variable <- eval(parse(text = paste0("result", i)))
    print(paste0(current_variable, " in interation_", i))
    # Set working directory to string in variable current_variable
    current_dir <- setwd(current_variable)
    print(paste0("current_dir: ",current_dir))

    # DO SOME OTHER STUFF WITH FILES IN THE CURRENT FOLDER
}

# Switch back into original directory
current_dir <- setwd(start_dir)
print(paste0("end_dir: ",current_dir))
```

The output is the following ...

```
[1] "start_dir: /home/user"
[1] "/home/user/folder1 in interation_1"
[1] "current_dir: /home/user"
[1] "/home/user/folder2 in interation_2"
[1] "current_dir: /home/user/folder1"
[1] "/home/user/folder3 in interation_3"
[1] "current_dir: /home/user/folder2"
[1] "end_dir: /home/user/folder3"
```

... while I would have expected this:

```
[1] "start_dir: /home/user"
[1] "/home/user/folder1 in interation_1"
[1] "current_dir: /home/user/folder1"
[1] "/home/user/folder2 in interation_2"
[1] "current_dir: /home/user/folder2"
[1] "/home/user/folder3 in interation_3"
[1] "current_dir: /home/user/folder3"
[1] "end_dir: /home/user/"
```

So it turns out that the path assigned to current_dir is somewhat "behind" ...

Why is this the case? 
As I am far away from being a R expert, I have no idea what is causing this behaviour and most important how to get the desired behaviour.
So any help, hint, code correction/optimization would be highly appreciated!

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) -- "Bug in Your Hair"
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `?setwd` help page...

> `setwd` returns the current directory before the change, invisibly and with the same conventions as `getwd`. It will give an error if it does not succeed (including if it is not implemented).

So when you do

```
current_dir <- setwd(current_variable)
print(paste0("current_dir: ",current_dir))
```

You are not getting the "current" directory, you are getting the previous one. You should use `getwd()` to get the current one

```
setwd(current_variable)
current_dir <- getwd()
print(paste0("current_dir: ",current_dir))
```

Comment: Okay, know I feel a little embaressed about not seeing where it goes wrong... but thanks a lot for the quick enlightment!